# jqGrid filterToolbar(): Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

So I'm trying to upgrade the jquery on a site i'm working on from 1.4 to 3.3, and I'm having issues with my jqgrid. I have a html table that i'm converting to a jqgrid using the tableToGrid function, and everything is fine until I try and add the filterToolbar. 
I'm also using jqGrid 5.3.1. Here's a snippet of the code

```
    <table id='warrantytable' class='tableinquiry' >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Item<br/>Number</th>
         <th>Order<br/>Number</th>
         <th>WH Status</th>
         <th>Kit SKU</th>
         <th>Purchase<br/>Source</th>
         <th>Store</th>
         <th>Effective<br/>Date</th>
         <th>Production<br/>Code</th>
         <th>Factory<br/>Code</th>
         <th>Smart<br/>Serial Number</th>
         <th>Actual<br/>Serial Number</th>
         <th>Serial<br/>Date</th>
         <th>Serial<br/>Factory Code</th>
         <th>Registration<br/>Date</th>
         <th>User ID</th>
         <th>Expiration<br/>Date</th>
         <th>Warranty<br/>Item</th>
         <th>Warranty<br/>Type</th>
         <th>Warranty<br/>Duration</th>
         <th>Edit</th>
         <th>Info</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class='highlight'>
         <td align='center'>S3101</td>
         <td align='center'>10000601-00</td>
         <td align='center'>Open Order</td>
         <td align='center'></td>
         <td align='center'>F156</td>
         <td align='center'></td>
         <td align='center'>08/29/18</td>
         <td align='center'></td>
         <td align='center'></td>
         <td align='center'></td>
         <td align='center'></td>
         <td align='center'></td>
         <td align='center'></td>
         <td align='center'>08/29/18</td>
         <td align='center'>sheldoN@fdm4.com</td>
         <td align='center'>03/05/20</td>
         <td align='center'></td>
         <td align='center'>Make-it-right</td>
         <td>554</td>
         <td><a onclick="javascript:_lastwarrantyrow = $('#warrantytable').jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow'); warrantyUpdate('','','no');"> <img class='imgstyle' title='Edit warranty' width='16px' height='16px' /></a></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>      
   </tbody>
</table>
<script>
tableToGrid('#warrantytable',{autowidth: true, forcefit: true  });
$('#warrantytable').each(function(){$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','Edit',{search: false});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','Edit',{sortable: false});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','Info',{search: false});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','Info',{sortable: false});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','ItemNumber',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','OrderNumber',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','WH_Status',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','Kit_SKU',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','PurchaseSource',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','Store',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','ProductionCode',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','FactoryCode',{searchoptions: {attr: {maxlength: 2}, clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','SmartSerialNumber',{searchoptions: {attr: {maxlength: 12}, clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','ActualSerialNumber',{searchoptions: {attr: {maxlength: 16}, clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','SerialDate',{searchoptions: {attr: {maxlength: 10}, clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','SerialFactoryCode',{searchoptions: {attr: {maxlength: 2}, clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','User_ID',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','ExpirationDate',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','WarrantyItem',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','WarrantyType',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','WarrantyDuration',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});

$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','EffectiveDate',{search: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'],dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/y',changeYear:true,onSelect:function(){if(this.id.substr(0,3) === 'gs_'){setTimeout(function(){$('#warrantytable')[0].triggerToolbar();},50);}else{$(this).trigger('change');}} }) } }});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','RegistrationDate',{search: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'],dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/y',changeYear:true,onSelect:function(){if(this.id.substr(0,3) === 'gs_'){setTimeout(function(){$('#warrantytable')[0].triggerToolbar();},50);}else{$(this).trigger('change');}} }) } }});;});

<!-- this is the error line -->
$("#warrantytable").filterToolbar({searchOperators : true});

if(_lastwarrantyrow != 0){$('#warrantytable').setSelection(_lastwarrantyrow,false);}

$(window).bind('resize', function() {$('#warrantytable').setGridWidth($(window).width() * 0.98);}).trigger('resize');
$(window).bind('resize', function() {winHeight = $(window).height();wHeight = winHeight - (winHeight * 0.5);if(wHeight < 125){wHeight = 125;}$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setGridHeight',wHeight); }).trigger('resize');
</script>
```

My grid still displays, the sorting/sizing/etc works, it just won't display the filter toolbar
[image: jqgrid display]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfect. You will need to check other things in it.
Here is [jsfiddle of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/guriddo/2go5wujv/).

Bellow part of code

```
var _lastwarrantyrow;
tableToGrid('#warrantytable',{autowidth: true, forcefit: true  });
$('#warrantytable').each(function(){$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','Edit',{search: false});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','Edit',{sortable: false});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','Info',{search: false});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','Info',{sortable: false});
$('#warrantytable').jqGrid('setColProp','ItemNumber',{searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}});
```